# PHP multiple redirects

Tags: php, redirect

I have a $_POST array with a single variable 'listing_type'. The form submits to a page containing the code below which redirects them to another page with more forms dependent on their initial choice. Is there a slicker way to do this? It works fine but feels clunky...

```
<?php // listing-type.php
if ((isset($_POST['listing_type'])) && (!empty($_POST['listing_type']))) {

    switch($_POST['listing_type']) {
        case "1":
            $url = "events/new-event.php";
            break;
        case "2":
            $url = "restaurants/new-restaurant.php";
            break;
        case "3":
            $url = "bars/new-bar.php";
            break;
        case "4":
            $url = "attractions/new-attraction.php";
            break;  
    }
header("Location: $url"); // Perform redirect to given new listing page
}
else {  // Redirect to homepage if no usuable listing_type data from form
    $url = "index.php";
    header("Location: $url");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine except there is no need to have two location calls, and you don't need the else:

```
$url = "index.php";
if ((isset($_POST['listing_type'])) && (!empty($_POST['listing_type']))) {
    // Switch statement
}

header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: And you don't need the `isset`, `empty` takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate using an array:

```
$urls = array("index.php",
              "events/new-event.php", 
              "restaurants/new-restaurant.php",
              "bars/new-bar.php",
              "attractions/new-attraction.php",);

$url = $urls[!empty($_POST['listing_type']) ? $_POST['listing_type'] : 0];
header("Location: $url"); // Perform redirect to given new listing page
exit;
```

Many combinations of the above.  Be advised that you don't need `empty` and `isset` on the same variable as in your code.  `empty` checks for both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. I think is a good way, you can improving your code a litle bit but is a good way.

Anyway, I think if you can do it this one with js during sending the form, o perhaps in you html code, you don't have to make a redirection and don't spent time, improving the speed of your website.